# Guess the number with Tkinter, Python3

Tags: python, tkinter

here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

def initGame():
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Guess the number game")

    lbl = Label(window, text="Guess number from 1 to 100. Insert how many tries would you like to have: ", font=("",16))
    lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

    txt = Entry(window, width=10)
    txt.grid(column=0, row=1)
    txt.focus() #place cursor auto
    def clicked():
        number_dirty = txt.get()
        tries = int(number_dirty)
        playGame(tries)

    btn = Button(window, text="Start", command=clicked)
    btn.grid(column=0, row=2)

    window.geometry('800x600')
    window.mainloop()

def playGame(tries):
    number_of_tries = int(tries)
    number = random.randint(1,100)
    higher_notification = "Number is HIGHER"
    lower_notification = "Number is LOWER"

    game_window = Tk()
    game_window.title("Game Window")

    lbl = Label(game_window, text="Guess numbers between 1 and 100, you have %s tries !" %(number_of_tries), font=("",14))
    lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
    txt = Entry(game_window, width=10)
    txt.grid(column=0, row=1)
    txt.focus()
    print(number)
    print(number_of_tries)
    def clicked():
        user_input = txt.get()
        compareNumbers(number, user_input)

    btn_try = Button(game_window, text="Try!", command="clicked")
    btn_try.grid(column=0, row=2)
    def compareNumbers(number, user_input):
        if user_input == number:
            messagebox.showinfo('You have won!', 'Right! the number was %s ' %(number))
        else:
            if user_input > number:
                lbl.configure(lower_notification)
                number_of_tries -1
            else:
                lbl.configure(higher_notification)
                number_of_tries -1

    game_window.geometry('600x600')
    game_window.mainloop()


initGame()
```

On the first screen (initGame) everything works fine, when I click the button I do indeed get the second screen, which displays all objects normally. When I click the button in the game screen I get no feedback at all, nothing happens.

What am I missing?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
btn_try = Button(game_window, text="Try!", command="clicked")
```

Note that the command "clicked" is inside quotaions marks and therefor a string and not the method you tried to reference. What you want is:

```
btn_try = Button(game_window, text="Try!", command=clicked)
```